# Generate rows with conditional values in a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a dataset with information for years 2010 to 2013. However, when there is no info on a given year, instead of having a row with `NA` the row doesn't exist.

```
datos <- data.frame(Country = c(rep("Australia", 3), rep("Belgium", 3)), 
     Year = c(2010, 2011, 2013, 2010, 2011, 2013), 
     Value = c(0.34, 0.35, 0.25, 0.30, 0.34, 0.38))
```

What I got:

```
  Country   Year  Value
1 Australia 2010   0.34
2 Australia 2011   0.35
3 Australia 2013   0.25
4   Belgium 2010   0.30
5   Belgium 2011   0.34
6   Belgium 2013   0.38
```

What I want: to create rows for the missing years on each `Country`, and impute the `Value` such that is the one from the previous year.

```
   Country   Year  Value
1 Australia 2010   0.34
2 Australia 2011   0.35
3 Australia 2012   0.35   #New row
4 Australia 2013   0.25
5   Belgium 2010   0.30
6   Belgium 2011   0.34
7   Belgium 2012   0.34   #New row
8   Belgium 2013   0.38
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @akrun for your answer. However, this didn't work on my dataset because it was too large and `fill()` expanded the dataset repeating combinations of `Country-Years` that didn't made sense to me. Googling around I came across `na.locf()` from the package `zoo`, which simply fills missing values using last or previous observation.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

complete(datos, Year = 2003:2016) %>%
na.locf()
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is one option with `complete`

```
library(tidyverse)
complete(datos, Country, Year = min(Year):max(Year)) %>% 
        fill(Value)
```